# SQL Tuning for IN Clause

Tags: oracle, teradata

The below Teradata query is taking around 18 seconds to complete.
The highlighted values passed in IN clause is from another Oracle database so I am not able to implement a join with that table.

```
SELECT distinct sec.SerialNum esn, ef.EngineFamilyCd family, em.EngineModelCd model,
es.EngineSeriesCd series, sac.AircraftTailNum tailNumRef, sec.EnginePositionNum enginePosition,
o1.OrganizationId ownerOrgId, o2.OrganizationId operatorOrgId,
sec.EngineInstallationDttm installedDate, sec.EngineRemovalDttm removalDate,
sec.HardwareConfigNm hardwareConfig, sec.EngineControlNm engineControl,
sec.ApplicationSelectorNm appSelector, sec.EngineMonitorInd engineMonitorInd,
sec.EngineThrustRatingFctr engineThrustRating, sec.StatusDesc engineStatus, sec.n1modifiernum n1modifier
FROM DB_MASTER_BV.SZEngineCurrent sec, 
 DB_MASTER_BV.EngineSeries es,
DB_MASTER_BV.EngineModel em,
DB_Master_BV.EngineFamily ef,
DB_MASTER_BV.SZAircraftCurrent sac, 
 DB_MASTER_BV.Organization o1, 
 DB_MASTER_BV.Organization o2 
 WHERE sec.EngineSeriesCd = es.EngineSeriesCd 
 and es.EngineModelCd = em.EngineModelCd 
 and  em.EngineFamilyCd = ef.EngineFamilyCd 
 and sec.MasterAircraftId = sac.MasterAircraftId 
 and o1.MasterOrganizationId = sec.OwnerMasterOrganizationId 
and o2.MasterOrganizationId = sec.OperatorMasterOrganizationId 
AND (sec.SerialNum in('733276','193283','690168','741471','876374','873383','193386','906397','804314','900116','785670','900399','724321','193488','811373','779917','193699','994688',
'779410','575169','A59299','900206','193297','575484','896359','367230','810105','876485','906385','876484','707149','811222','706801','193596','731949','697881',
'889697','804626','575194','707159','706129','900230','900231','706834','811352','900229','785748','193460','888221','906272','906266','906264','906263','994356',
'194431','731966','892417','811341','577413','741572','575564','889262','706956','876157','900257','900153','706958','706957','960436','892429','892427','900354',
'697138','645655','193352','994337','707189','697833','959190','900246','811317','577437','193643','697976','890692','193229','965579','900137','900135','894897',
'697723','193363','193367','785505','907077','959184','811311','706526','577302','706529','994332','702792','706663','779834','731931','960127','193371','876183',
'741563','193235','803843','577320','994318','907087','741460','907086','959170','994462','900464','193626','877503','643711','811202','811201','704585','193504',
'193500','875246','704876','725834','699783','699780','802380','900304','706885','906191','577773','959152','872574','811435','697388','699381','892485','577698',
'907035','811445','907039','894999','894857','894595','697273','894597','959139','577894','874898','706959','900424','193337','577697','907011','875696','699555',
'699554','575629','906149','906150','193452','962968','811264','811266','962970','875395','699543','575638','906153','857962','896247','858349','779746','906161',
'906928','802857','779640','193424','550309','424520','550305','575608','872517','906169','892196','811386','811385','906173','907220','959234','876666','959231',
'876662','893785','875914','802649','550218','550315','906111','741984','550319','906405','906501','550118','643371','785254','550116','550117','802946','906629',
'907145','550325','550324','906837','550320','906838','702591','550220','550227','906415','690289','906517','704416','731431','550125','959201','906413','994176',
'550333','550140','550337','891651','550141','550338','906746','907269','550132','550137','550138','892914','550342','906123','550153','550345','950923','906129',
'873188','906850','906953','690270','890713','645352','893127','697590','874826','424439','893126','907110','550144','856305','690269','892824','550256','550257',
'906867','907186','960852','720754','960851','906866','888607','805573','811530','960756','872352','550266','550267','550264','811518','888896','906730','994958',
'892247','960970','875186','906987','424124','550232','A59303','702660','875885','811609','888626','424219','906897','994981','731502','697496','695345','962996',
'894371','907153','805541','907154','424337','906613','906615','900512','906610','956141','994611','804582','994718','888648','575219','888756','896973','424395',
'872117','A59227','697616','731380','697614','900161','690410','994213','956155','956154','779492','994231','702876','577248','994727','193818','890879','722243',
'906499','577354','888560','645121','896972','960823','804279','900175','888853','193724','550285','550282','906469','994803','906466','888299','877141','890984',
'695688','994533','888327','A59348','A59346','994410','733116','550296','550290','550292','906478','731763','725658','896408','645145','994751','731654','740358',
'906441','550158','193849','906543','906448','994262','575824','424186','906345','643663','888305','906243','906244','702963','906453','906452','956119','906451',
'956116','950489','550166','906454','367457','896764','575833','994268','906252','994127','733236','906258','956123','550178','994777','956126','956127','956128',
'906786','906788','906687','643290','994631','956225','994632','888574','906365','804228','731599','643682','550182','804369','994784','550186','550183','888826',
'575127','906439','890482','906438','906691','890472','994509','193147','575718','804215','575276','994793','897257'))
and END(sec.EngineValidPd) is until_changed 
 order by esn
```

Also if there is more than 1000 records, I am implementing the IN clause as follows 
AND (sec.SerialNum in( first 999 recods) OR sec.SerialNum in( next 999 recods)… OR sec.SerialNum in( remaining recods))
Please suggest solution which would be faster than the above query and  which will not cause issue with more than 1000 records in IN clause

Comment: If you're able to generate a query like the above, from the data in the Oracle database, why don't you put the SerialNum's inside a temporary table in your Teradata database, and then do the query with a join against the temporary table?

Comment: This approach is not scalable and eventually will lead to problems. I would agree with Dan that you should load these values into a temporary table on Teradata.

Answer (score 1):

> What is your Teradata release?

In TD14 there's a built-in table function to split a string of values, you can simply pass all values within a single string:

```
AND sec.SerialNum IN
 (
   SELECT token
   FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, '733276,193283,690168,741471,876374', ',')
        RETURNS (outkey INTEGER,
                 tokennum INTEGER,
                 token VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
              ) AS d
 )
```